# bt yahoo comes on every tab

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer

I use internet explorer. I recently downloaded a programme and it has highjacked by my search dial. I managed to get rid of it by setting the homepage (Bt yahoo) to default. However, every time I open a tab it goes on the bt yahoo homepage instead of the top sites. How can I get the top sites back? The software I use is Windows vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go into your `Internet Options` - Click on the `General` Tab (it is the default tab) - Click on the button labelled `Tabs`

On the dialog that appears, under where it says "When a new tab is opened, open:" choose `The new tab page` from the drop-down menu.